# AEM 6.3 Classic UI issue in overlay functionality error "TypeError: CQ.security.data is undefined"

Tags: aem

In AEM 6.3 classic UI, When i am trying to overlay

```
/libs/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/security/data/AclStore.js
```

to

```
/apps/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/security/data/AclStore.js
```

the following error is coming

> TypeError: CQ.security.data is undefined CQ.security.data.UserAclStore
>   = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.security.data.AclStore,{

Like this we are getting error for all the overlay js has issue in AEM 6.3
[image]

Comment: What does this question have to do with extjs?

Comment: extjs is not causing any problem here. But AEM 6.3 overlay function is causing problem. basically after overlay a single client lib file to apps the remaining files are not loading which is available in libs. Sling resource Merger is having some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe the Sling Resource Resolution kicks in when resolving the contents of client libraries.

To extend the OOTB functionality, you need to:

- create your own client library with a dependency to the original
- be part of the appropriate category
- override the functions/objects as you desire

More info: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/extending/customizing-page-authoring-touch.html

The Sling Resource Merger itself seems to be only applicable to Touch UI and I've only ever used it when making changes to the authoring UI (i.e. navigation menus)

> The Sling Resource Merger and related methods can only be used with Granite. This also means that it is only appropriate for the touch-optimized UI; in particular overrides defined in this manner are only applicable for the touch-optimized dialog of a component.

source: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/platform/sling-resource-merger.html

Comment: I am agree your answer for Touch UI. We are using Classic UI, so i have tried the below approach and that is resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue using the below logic. Clientlibs js file creation logic is differed in AEM 6.3.

In AEM 6.1 Clientlibs js creation is binding the overlaid files from  /apps/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/js.txt and non overlaid files from /libs/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/js.txt

In AEM 6.3 Clientlibs js creation is binding files from /apps/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/js.txt only.

Because of this non overlaid files (CQ.security.js) are not binding into clientlibs js(widgets.js) and its gives the below error

> TypeError: CQ.security.data is undefined CQ.security.data.UserAclStore
> = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.security.data.AclStore,{
>
> So i have merged the js.txt of
> /libs/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/js.txt into
> /apps/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/js.txt and it's resolved the
> issue.

Please provide your answer if there is any other way to resolve this issue.